# Sort an array using another array in strictly same order typescript

Tags: javascript, arrays, typescript, sorting, lodash

I am trying to sort this array

```
const originalArray = ['Apple', 'Cat', 'Fan', 'Zebra', 'Goat', 'Van'];
```

using this array

```
const sortOrder = ['Zebra', 'Van', "Cat"];
```

I have tried to use this method;

```
const sortedArray = originalArray.sort((a, b) => {
  return sortOrder.indexOf(b) - sortOrder.indexOf(a);
});

console.log(sortedArray) // Output:["Cat","Van","Zebra","Apple","Fan","Goat"]
```

Although this is not the expected result

The expected Output should be like this

```
["Zebra","Van","Cat","Apple","Fan","Goat"]
```

Open to any solution using any library as well like lodash.
Thanks in advance

Comment: To reverse the sort order reverse how you compare the items: `sortOrder.indexOf(b) - sortOrder.indexOf(a)` -> `sortOrder.indexOf(a) - sortOrder.indexOf(b)`

Comment: That is adding the sorted values at the end of the array, but I want it in the start of the array.

Comment: I can't see that this is a typescript question?

Comment: If I would be using any library like lodash the typescript was throwing errors

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could take an object with the order and for not known items take a large value to sort them to the end of the array

```js
const
    array = ['Apple', 'Cat', 'Fan', 'Zebra', 'Goat', 'Van'],
    sortOrder = ['Zebra', 'Van', "Cat"],
    order = Object.fromEntries(sortOrder.map((k, i) => [k, i + 1]));

array.sort((a, b) =>
    (order[a] || Number.MAX_VALUE) - (order[b] || Number.MAX_VALUE)
);

console.log(array);
```

Comment: I am getting an error 
`Property 'default' does not exist on type '[string, unknown][]`

Comment: you could take `Number.MAX_VALUE` directly. please see edit.

Comment: Yes it worked, thankyou so much, actually my use case it in the list I am trying to add fav values and those fav values must be in the top in the same order of the chosen, thank you so much. You are a life saver.

Comment: Can you please give me a little explanation of what is happening there in the sort and why we took MAX_VALUE

Comment: basically i sorts by index (plus one, because we need the falsy zero later) with delta (this is standard) and by using another value if zero for sorting unknown values behind known one. `Number.MAX_VALUE` is larger than any other index value (32 bit positive).

Answer (score 1):

Try sort it with reverse of `sortOrder`

```js
const originalArray = ['Apple', 'Cat', 'Fan', 'Zebra', 'Goat', 'Van'];
const sortOrder = ['Zebra', 'Van', "Cat"];

// reverse the `sortOrder`
let reverseOrder = sortOrder.reverse();

// if you want to keep `sortOrder` as it is
// then do slice() and then reverse()
// let reverseOrder = sortOrder.slice().reverse();

// The key point here is to sort by reverse of `sortOrder`
let sortedArray = originalArray.sort((a, b) => {
  return reverseOrder.indexOf(b) - reverseOrder.indexOf(a);
})

console.log(sortedArray)
```